# How to store a Date object in SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Is it possible to store a `Date` object using `SharedPreferences`?

Actually in my code I have a `String` variable, `boolean` and `Date`. Here is my function for storing all the objects except `Date`. So how that can be done please suggest me?

```
private void SavePreferences() {

    String key="1";
    String value="hello";

    int x=5;

    Date currentDate=new Date();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_APPEND);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);

    editor.putInt("2",5);

    editor.commit();
}
```

So my question is how to store the `Date` using `SharedPreferences`?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
editor.putLong("THE_DATE", currentDate.getTime());
```

And you can read a `Date` from preferences like this:

```
long millis = sharedPreferences.getLong("THE_DATE", 0L);
Date theDate = new Date(millis);
```

Comment: once i stored data..and again open the application..i have a reset button..once i click on the reset button is it possible to remove  all these stored data..that i have stored using shredPreferences.

Comment: Simple, great answer.

Answer (score 3):

Set Date Time

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_APPEND);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
Date dt = getSomeDate();
editor.putLong(dateTimeKey, dt.getTime());
```

Get Date Time

```
long myDate = sharedPreferences.getLong(dateTimeKey, new Date().getTime());
```

Comment: You can't have a variable named `long`, it's a keyword.

Comment: oops sorry, I have change it to myDate, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

you can store the date value using sharedpreferences like this way

```
editor.putLong("date",currentDate.getTime());
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `Date` as formatted `String`, e.g.

```
//for putting
Date myDate;
final String FORMAT="yyyy-MM-dd";
String prefData=SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT).format(myDate);
editor.putString("Date", prefDate);

//for reading
prefDate=settings.getString("Date", "");
Date date=new SimpleDateFormat(FORMAT).parse(prefDate);
```

Or you can put millis as Long

Comment: ok its fine but when i try to stored my second date it will overide the first date it store..so how that can be maintain..so that each time i add date it will store new date without overidding the previous date.

Comment: Store second data with different key, say putString("date1", myDate1) and putString("date2", myDate2);