# Date Preference exist?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have some preferences (EditText and ListPreference) and i have to add a date preference in the XML file. is that possible and is it existing in sharedpreferences ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure there is not a date picker for shared preferences, you would most likely have to create your own. You can however store a date into a preference using the

```
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    //editor.putLong(key, Long);
    editor.putLong("thecurrentdate", currentDate.getTime());
```

This would store the date into a preference, in your case you could store it into the EditText preference.

Maybe this post would help you? 
[How to store a Date object in SharedPreferences?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6610284/how-to-use-sharedpreferences)

Hope this helps!